# jQuery terminal: how to unset mask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

I'm using [jQuery Terminal](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal) to build my site.

Now I'm building `signin` command:

```js
signin: function() {
  this.read("user id: ").then(userId =>
  this.set_mask('*').read("password: ").then(password =>
    // signin process
  ));
}
```

This code works correctly.
But after this process `set_mask('*')` will remain.

I've tried `this.set_mask(false);` but it doesn't work.
How to unset this mask?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

My solution and here is an example of variable declarations and a bit of code.

```js
var term = $(".terminal").terminal({
  signin: function() {
    this.read("user id: ").then(userId =>
    this.set_mask('*').read("password: ").then(password =>
      // signin process
    term.set_mask(false);    // it works!
    // this.set_mask(false); // it doesn't work
    ));
  }
});
```

Thank you and hope this code will help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that helps.

```js
set_mask is defined as a boolean
set_mask(false or true)
```

I'm not familiar with Jquery Terminal.
Maybe you can use for example if (mask....) {

```
mask
```

Just explore the examples https://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php

Comment: I've solved this problem, thank you for your help!

Comment: @pyxgun if you solved the issue and not with this answer then maybe you should create own answer so others will benefit. Answers like this is not useful to anybody (note that this looks like question and single answer never mind I solve it).